# How to pop only the circular progress indicator in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

'''buildShowDialog(BuildContext context) {
return showDialog(
context: context,
barrierDismissible: false,
builder: (BuildContext cont1) {
return Center(
child: LoadingAnimationWidget.threeArchedCircle(
color: Colors.white, size: 50),
);
});
}

loginFunction(http.Client client, jsonBody) async {
buildShowDialog(context);

```
var url = Uri.parse("https://my-office-timesheet.herokuapp.com/api/signin");
var respsonse = await client.post(url, body: jsonBody);

if (respsonse.statusCode == 200) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
  if (this.mounted) {
    setState(() {
      jsonResponse = Post.fromJson(json.decode(respsonse.body));
    });
  }
  if (jsonResponse!.success == true) {
    if (this.mounted) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Dashboard()),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      //this code is to route without a back button.
    }
  } else {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text("Message:"),
        content: Text("${jsonResponse?.message}"),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
              if (this.mounted) {
                setState(() {
                  jsonResponse = null;
                });
              }
            },
            child: const Text("Ok"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

return respsonse;
```

}'''

```
List view builder

ListView.builder(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: _fieldNames.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            FieldBuilderForm(
                              key: ValueKey(index),
                              fieldColor: _fieldColor[index],
                              fieldTextColor: _fieldTextColor[index],
                              fieldName: _fieldNames[index],
                              controller: controller[index],
                              size: displaySize,
                            ),
```

In the above code when I pop the LoadingAnimationWidget. The list view builder which I made is the one popping instead. Any suggestions?